# jquery RegularExpression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace `0` in `widget-cadr_testimonials[1][slides][0][slide_title]`

`var patt1=/\d+/g;`  // this is returning the two found integers 1,0 and I need only 0 and want to replace it

```
var str="widget-cadr_testimonials[1][slides][0][slide_title]";
var patt1=/\d+/g;
document.write(str.match(patt1));
```

Comment: what do you want to replace it with?

Comment: Could that string also be `widget-cadr_testimonials[0][slides][0][slide_title]`? Or is it safe to assume a single `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str.replace(/\d+([^\d]+)$/,'x$1');//Where 'x' is your replacement
```

To just get the matched number you can debug:

```
str.match(/(\d+)[^\d]+$/)[1]
```

Or if you want to be more specific about the text either side:

```
str.replace(/\[\d+\](\[slide_title)/,'[x]$1')
```

Comment: Your answer was faster and more complete than my new one, as it also does the replace correctly. I deleted mine in favor of this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you really only want to replace the only 0 in that specific string, why don't you do this:

```
var str="widget-cadr_testimonials[1][slides][0][slide_title]".replace("0", "x");
```

(where x is whatever you want to replace the 0 with)

Comment: because the second integer match it's dynamic , and it will always be other value

So I need to get second match and replace it

Comment: Ah, I see. Please try to be as complete as possible when asking a question, we can't read your mind ;). I'll post a new answer. The rest of the string does remain the same?

Comment: sorry my english is bad , yes the rest of the string remain same

Comment: Your English is not a problem, it's just that some important information was missing. I posted a new answer.